# What is the term for mimicking other behaviors?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology, neuroimaging

Say you see an actor playing someone insane, for the next few hours you feel kind of crazy too, especially if you are tired. You may feel annoyed and overwhelmed and mad for no reason, and kind of skwirmy for lack of better words.

Is this a recognized phenomenon? If so, what’s it called?

Comment: mimicking others is a well-known phenomenon. You can look at some videos of neuroimaging in YouTube.

Comment: @Ooker - do you think this Q is worth re-opening? It's not self-help, but as of now it's vague and really broad. I'm afraid it will end up in a discussion thread than anything else. Its foundations are still based on one anecdotal observation.

Comment: @AliceD [let's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49099338#49099338)

Comment: @Ooker - I'm at work. Can't chat. Not able to for the next 7 hours either. Sorry! I'll respond asap

Comment: @AliceD no problem, just take your time

Comment: I understand why this is too vague, but I still fully get what he's asking and where else is James gonna ask this? I think there should be another stackexchange site for this kinda stuff. For now I'd re-open it.

Comment: @MarkDeven you can join the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49099338#49099338)